# Disable touch-scroll in ionic iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, canvas, dom-events

I have a canvas element to put user's signature that can be drawn by there touch and move. It works okay with Android version. However, iOS has touch-scroll effect and whenever I try to draw on the signature canvas, the screen moves along with it so I cannot really draw anything.

I tried to disable touch-scroll effect whenever user touch and moves in signature canvas element, but couldn't find any sound answer.

I am wondering if any of you have an answer for this problem.